# How to get info about changes in folder from background

Tags: swift, filesystems, grand-central-dispatch

I have an application that should monitor changes in folder Documents when it is in background mode. I have implemented done it using GCD, here my code:

```
    fileDescriptor = open(folderToMonitor.path, O_CREAT, 0o644)

    dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Monitor")

    source = DispatchSource.makeFileSystemObjectSource(fileDescriptor: fileDescriptor, eventMask: .all, queue: dispatchQueue)

    source.setEventHandler {
        [weak self] in
        if self?.delegate != nil {
            self?.delegate?.didChangeHappend()
        }
    }
    source.setCancelHandler { 
        [weak self] in
        self?.delegate = nil
        guard let desc = self?.fileDescriptor else { return }
        close(desc)
    }
    source.resume()
```

I receive notification, but how could I identify what change happened in folder, whether it was renamed, file or folder deleted, added and so on.

Comment: `notification.userInfo` might have relevant information could you check that ?

Comment: @ user1046037, thank you). I do not exactly use NSNotifications, cause they do not work properly in background mode, maybe I wasn't clear, what i meant is that I receive notice  about changes by firing callback in  source.setEventHandler, and after that I need to get to know what exactly happend in that folder.

Comment: use eventMask and separate handlers

Comment: @user3441734 thank you, but could you please clarify how exactly to do that?

Comment: change eventMask: .all to something more specific. create the source for every event which you would like to "monitor"

Comment: @user3441734, so in this case i will have several sources, well its idea. Thank you. You can post it as an answer I will accept))